# multiple panes with tmuxinator

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I' trying to build a tmuxinator with multiple windows and in one of them i`d like to build 2 panes:

```
name: bigbang-server
root: ~/projects/bigbang

windows:
  - CORE:
    - ...
  - CONSOLE:
    - ...
  - FUND_TRANSACTIONS:
    - ...
  - CLIENT_POSITIONS:
    pre_window: cd ~/projects/bigbang_services/
    panes:
      server:
        - env PORT=3002 rails server
      sidekiq:
        - bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

it doesnt run any of my last window commands, here its debug:

```
 # Window "CLIENT_POSITIONS"


  tmux select-window -t 1
  tmux select-pane -t 0

  if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    tmux -u attach-session -t bigbang-server
  else
    tmux -u switch-client -t bigbang-server
  fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote the commands for the panes in that particular window is wrong.
It should have been something like this:

```
windows:
    - CLIENT_POSTIONS:
        panes:
            - cd ~/projects/bigbang_services/
            - env PORT=3002 rails server
            - bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

This creates 2 horizontal splits first then splits the first one vertically.

To use horizontal or vertical splits throughout the window,
use `main-horizontal` or `main-vertical`.

Like this:

```
windows:
    - CLIENT_POSTIONS:
        layout: main-vertical # or main-horizontal
        panes:
            - cd ~/projects/bigbang_services/
            - env PORT=3002 rails server
            - bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some points to fix.

1. `pre_window:` should be top-level, not under `windows:`.
2. Any hash element (like `name:`) is not allowed under the `pane:`.

Like this.

```
name: bigbang-server
root: ~/projects/bigbang
pre_window: cd ~/projects/bigbang_services/
windows:
  - CORE:
    - ...
  - CONSOLE:
    - ...
  - FUND_TRANSACTIONS:
    - ...
  - CLIENT_POSITIONS:
      panes:
        - env PORT=3002 rails server
        - bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Comment: but i`d like to put different panes in different dirs